# What are the TS, MBD keywords for new (5.4.+) VASP versions?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, dispersion-correction

I tried `IVDW = 2202` for MBD as mentioned on the website but I got the following error:

```
INITWF: ERROR, W inconsistently dimensioned:  1
```

I think some other keywords are missing but it does not mention them on the website. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think we will need to see more of your input, as well as a description of what you are trying to do, before we can provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Tyberius shall we give the user a chance to respond to your advice before closing it? I typically wait until the user has totally ignored all requests for more details/clarity before flagging it as an "abandoned question".

Comment: @Nike I figured they haven't been back since mid-March so they are likely to be gone for awhile if not permanently. If they do return and respond, I can reopen it, but until they do it would just be sitting in the unanswered queue.

Comment: @Tyberius indeed it's an *unregistered user* that was *very* active for a few months, then suddenly disappeared in mid-March. Perhaps see if their IP address indicates anything about sockpuppetting.